# desired_word_found variable is not being changed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I was writing a simple program in Python that determines if a word is contained in a piece of text. The problem is that when the desired_word is detected in the piece of text the desired_word_found variable is not being changed by the statement "desired_word_found == true". I know this has something to do with the variable (desired_word_found) not being static and I even tried to change the variable to global but it still wasn't being changed by that statement. Im new to Python and need some help in this please.

#this program determines if a given word is in a piece of text

```
desired_word_found = False 


#retrieving necessary data 
desired_word = input("What word would you like to search for? ")
raw_text = input("Please enter the text you would like us to search: ")

words = raw_text.split()#stores each word of the text in words list 



for i in range(len(words)):#loops through list of words to determine if our desired word is contained in the list 

    if words[i] == desired_word:
        desired_word_found == True ################### VARIABLE IS NOT BEING CHANGED BY THIS STATEMENT


if desired_word_found == True:
    print(desired_word+" was found")
else:
    print(desired_word+" was not found")
```

Comment: the output is always "desired_word was not found", even when the word was found in the text by my loop. I isolated the problem to the desired_word_found variable not being changed by the statement marked with the "############"

Comment: You could also just have done `if desired_word in words: print("xxx")`. No need to loop over and check each word.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a value to a variable is done by ONE equals mark:

```
desired_word_found = True
```